# Consistent way of declaring class fields in Scala

Tags: scala, constructor

This constantly bugs me:

```
class Test(i: Int) {
  val this.i = i;
  val this.ii = i; // :(
}
```

I would like to declare all my vals/vars the same way, and I really don't understand why that **this** upsets the Scala compiler. Everywhere else **this** performs as expected except here.

1. Is there a good reason why it won't let me punch in that **this**?
2. Is there *a better way*/ *a way around it*/ *a Scala way*?

Comment: It looks like you are mixing JS (or maybe Ruby too) syntax with Scala.

Answer (score 9):

Every variable you declare in that scope is going to be a field. So it warrants no special syntax.

```
class Test(_i: Int) {
  val i = _i
  val ii = i
}
```

Or even better:

```
class Test(val i: Int) {
  val ii = i
}
```

You can write it either way, depending on whether you are going for clearer and smaller code OR "consistent" code.

Answer (score 3):

The scala way is not to use `this`. Why do you use this in Java? To make it obvious that you are accessing a member of an instance and not a static member. This isn't necessary in Scala, since there are no static members and members of the companion object need to be prefixed with the companion object's name anyway.